# Date format conversion results in 'Call to a member function format() on a non-object error'

Tags: php, datetime, string-formatting

I've tried all the answers to this common question on SO and I still can't get this to work. Here's my code:

```
$datetime = strip_tags($object->field_field_date[0]['rendered']['#markup']);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, F d, Y - H:s', $datetime);
$date = $dt->format('l, M\. jS \a\t g:s a'); // ERROR
```

This:

```
var_dump($datetime);
var_dump($dt);
```

Returns this:

```
string(33) "Friday, September 4, 2015 - 18:00"
object(DateTime)#501 (3) { ["date"]=>string(26) "2015-09-04 18:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
```

I assume there's something wrong with the `$datetime` variable, because if I use the following I no longer get the error.

```
$datetime = strip_tags('<b>Friday, September 4, 2015 - 18:00</b>');
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/422942)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more error handling will help...

```
$datetime = strip_tags($object->field_field_date[0]['rendered']['#markup']);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, F d, Y - H:s', $datetime);
if ( !is_object($dt) ) {
    trigger_error( sprintf('failed to create datetime from [%s]', $object->field_field_date[0]['rendered']['#markup']) );
}
else {
    $date = $dt->format('l, M\. jS \a\t g:s a');
```

Comment: This is helpful. My above code is in a loop, and your suggestion reveals that there's a problem with the data in the first instance, which was causing the entire script to fail. Still need more investigation, but I'm getting closer. Thanks.